# Strange issue with jQueryUI and .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: jquery-ui, .htaccess

I have the following rule in my .htaccess which redirects any requests for `/labs/...` to `/projects/...`:

```
RewriteRule ^labs/(.+)$ projects/$1 [L]
```

Where `projects` is a local folder on my web server.  I'm using jQueryUI on a page in a subfolder of `projects`, say `projects/project1/index.php`.

When I hit `http://mydomain.com/projects/project1/` everything is fine.  However if I hit `http://mydomain.com/labs/project1/` almost everything is fine, except that I get the following warning in my JS console:

```
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html. ui-bg_highlight-soft_60_4ca20b_1x100.png
```

And my jQueryUI button loses its glossy look. Note that all other images are fine - it's just this one particular PNG. It seems like the jQueryUI code might be doing something special/different here.

I don't even know where to begin to try to solve this. But if anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Specific example**:

Real path: http://grinninggecko.com/projects/retranslate/

Rewritten path: http://grinninggecko.com/labs/retranslate/

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this? Your given links now look awfully different.

Comment: Ya, I ended up changing paths around. The issue technically still exists, but instead of using a relative path to reference the jQuery UI CSS I used an absolute one, referencing the non-rewritten path.  This seemed to do the trick as an adequate workaround, but still doesn't explain why the rewritten path has an issue loading the CSS images properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver serves PNG files as text/html you can add this line to your .htaccess:

```
AddType image/png .png
```

Comment: Just tried that but it didn't make any difference. It doesn't appear that my webserver is serving PNGs in general as text/html, only in the case of this one particular PNG.